# Variance of $\hat{b} =\underset{b}{\mathrm{argmin}} \sum_{t=1}^N [y_t - bu_t]^2 $

Tags: statistics, signal-processing, covariance, time-series

We have $y_t = bu_t + e_t$ where $u_t$ is the input signal and I'm trying to find an expression for the variance of the estimate for b that is determined to be

$$\hat{b} = \underset{b}{\mathrm{argmin}} \sum_{t=1}^N [y_t - bu_t]^2 $$

Any ideas?
The arg min confuses me because because I can't just calculate the variance of the entire sum that would be pointless?

Comment: How did you get that $\hat b_N=\frac {\sum_{i=1}^N y_t}{\sum_{i=1}^N u_t}$ ? And is $D$ your expression for the variance?

Comment: That was a mistake. Differentiate the objective function to get $\sum_{i=1}^N (y_t-bu_t)u_t=0$ and solve for $b$. (Yes, $D$ stands for $var$).

Comment: Ok think I got it now, Thanks!